# How do I remove the cartridge from this "Bach" fixture?

Tags: repair, plumbing-fixture, identify-a-tool

[image: "Bach" faucet cartridge stem]
[image: "Bach" faucet cartridge stem view 2]

Photos are the key here; pictured is a single handle faucet which appears to be labeled “Bach” (not sure if that is brand or model).

The outer brass collar has a notch all the way around (not a thread) and the brass is split at the bottom, which sort of makes me think it should be squeezed like a retention clip, except that the nylon inner portion won’t let it compress at all.

That inner nylon appears to be threaded into the brass, however it isn’t sturdy enough to take any sort of wrench without tearing.

Is there some sort of custom wrench that I’ve yet to run across which would allow me to turn the nylon insert without damaging it?

*the Phillips head is just for landing the set screw for the handle, already tried removing it, to no avail*

Comment: the first picture shows that a custom wrench is required